# How to call a reference to myArray[Symbol.iterator]

Tags: javascript, iterator, symbols

I don't understand the meaning of the following error. What I want to do is store a reference to myIteratble[Symbol.iterator] and call it later. But I get the following error.

```
let str = 'foo';
let gen = str[Symbol.iterator];
console.log(typeof gen);    // 'function'
let it = gen();             // ERROR: Can't convert undefined to object.
```

Why can't I call gen? I realize I can work around this with the following hack:

```
let gen = function* () {
    let it = str[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (let n = it.next(); !n.done; n = it.next()) {
        yield n.value;
    }
}
```

But I would like to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator depends on its calling context being the base object, which is missing in your example. Use `.bind` to ensure that its calling context is your `str`:

```js
const str = 'foo';
const gen = str[Symbol.iterator].bind(str);
const it = gen(); 
console.log(it.next());
```